# R check elementwise if data.frame entries belong to vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to test whether each element of a data.frame belongs to some given vector. Consider the following example:

```
my_df<- data.frame(matrix(1:9 %% 4, nrow=3))
my_df
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  0  3
# 2  2  1  0
# 3  3  2  1

# Actually does what I want to do
my_df == c(1, 2)
#         X1    X2    X3
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

# Does not achieve what I am aiming at,
# seems to compare the objects line-by-line
my_df == c(1, 2, 3)
#        X1    X2    X3
# [1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Why does the operator `==` behave differently in the two examples above and where can I find documentation on this behaviour? How can I achieve an elementwise comparison that works independenlty of the vector's length?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You want `my_df == 1 | my_df == 2 | my_df == 3` ?

Comment: Yeah that works but my vector is long and I can't forsee it's values in advance. You have any idea how to do it using the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want a result like `my_df == 1 | my_df == 2 | my_df == 3` you can use `%in%`:

```
sapply(my_df, `%in%`, c(1, 2, 3))
#       X1    X2    X3
#[1,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[2,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

my_df == 1 | my_df == 2 | my_df == 3
#       X1    X2    X3
#[1,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[2,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

To the question where you can find documentation on this behaviour of `==`? `?"=="` gives: *The elements of shorter vectors are recycled as necessary.*

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The other answers show you how to do what you want. The *reason* it's working differently is due to **recycling**.

I'll start with two insane examples:

```r
my_df == c(1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,99)
#        X1   X2    X3
# [1,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE FALSE
my_df == c(1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0) # remove the last element
#        X1   X2   X3
# [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In the second example, the vector length is one short (only 8), so it takes the first element as a recycled element, so that makes the comparison vector equivalent to `c(1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1)`.

Now, let's look at why your first one succeeded: it is taking `c(1,2)` and recycling to the length of the frame, which is really just a column-wise elongation of it. Your call `my_df == c(1,2)` is effectively

```r
unlist(c(my_df))
# X11 X12 X13 X21 X22 X23 X31 X32 X33 
#   1   2   3   0   1   2   3   0   1 

c(1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1) == c(1, 2)
## which is recycled into
c(1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1) == c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
## which, when wrapped, shows that the 1s and 2s line up
c(1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1) ==
c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
```

Now we do the same thing with `c(1,2,3)`:

```r
c(1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1) == c(1, 2, 3)
c(1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1) == c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)

c(1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1) ==
c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

i.e., misalignment of the vectors.

Bottom line, do not rely on `==` to see what elements are in a frame.

Comment: Thank you, very insightful answer!

Comment: I also tried to touch the reason with: *The elements of shorter vectors are recycled as necessary.* But here its describe in a much better way!

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
MyFunction <- function(x){
  x %in% c(1:3)
}
sapply(my_df, MyFunction)
```

Output:

```
       X1    X2    X3
[1,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

But I don't know why your code doesn't behave as intended